# Getting below error when using local_search method in google maps API

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Code snippet :

import googlemaps
from datetime import datetime
import urllib

keyval = 'My_API_key'
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=keyval)

now = datetime.now()

directions_result = gmaps.directions("Pune",
                                     "Mumbai",
                                     mode="transit",
                                     departure_time=now)

local = gmaps.local_search('sushi san francisco, ca')

print directions_result

Error :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vuclip\workspace\Recommendation\code.py", line 26, in 
    local = gmaps.local_search('sushi san francisco, ca')
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'local_search'

I am getting this error when calling local_search method.
As per documentations,local_search Searches Google Local for the string query and returns a dictionary of the results.

Please help.